# C# Binding Navigator Page Change Event

Tags: c#, bindingnavigator

I am using a binding navigator and, when you click on one of the buttons (forward, back, etc), it changes to a different record in the dataset.

I have a method that has to happen with the new data when the user gets to a new page.  I can't seem to find an "Entered New Page" event on the navigator.  There is enter and leave but that just has to do with the control not the actual change of records.  I need to run my event when the record changes.  Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, after spending 10 hours, I post my question then figure it out.  Maybe this will help you save some time:

On your binding source, put your code in the event for:

BindingSource_CurrentChanged

Comment: Sorry that you spent 10 hours, but you saved me those 10 hours.